# Check if a string contains valid pattern in Bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have a file a.txt contains a string like:
Axxx-Bxxxx
Rules for checking if it is valid or not include:

- length is 10 characters.
- x here is digits only.

Then, I try to check with:

```
#!/bin/bash
exp_len=10;
file=a.txt;
msg="checking string";
tmp="File not exist";

echo $msg;
if[ -f $file];then
    tmp=$(cat $file);
    if[[${#tmp} != $exp_len ]];then
        msg="invalid length";
    elif [[ $tmp =~ ^[A[0-9]{3}-B[0-9]{4}]$]];then
        msg="valid";
    else
        msg="invalid";
    fi
else
    msg="file not exist";
fi
echo $msg;
```

But in valid case it doesn't work...
Is there someone help to correct me?
Thanks :)

Comment: Remove extra `[...]`s to make it `^A[0-9]{3}-B[0-9]{4}$`

Comment: Try `^A[0-9]{3}-B[0-9]{4}$`

Comment: As an aside, nearly all the semicolons here are redundant. A semicolon is basically a synonym for newline in the shell.

Comment: Paste your code into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) first to fix the most grave errors. BTW, why do you check for the length in a separate step? The length check also occurs implicitly via your regexp.

Comment: Thanks you for your help. Its due to i created this question on my mobile phone only. My current pc doesn't allow to access internet :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the regex fix, your code can be refactored as well, moreover there are syntax issues as well. Consider this code:

```bash
file="a.txt"
msg="checking string"
tmp="File not exist"

echo "$msg"

if [[ -f $file ]]; then
    s="$(<$file)"
    if [[ $s =~ ^A[0-9]{3}-B[0-9]{4}$ ]]; then
        msg="valid"
    else
        msg="invalid"
    fi
else
    msg="file not exist"
fi

echo "$msg"
```

Changes are:

- Remove unnecessary `cat`
- Use `[[ ... ]]` when using `bash`
- Spaces inside `[[ ... ]]` are required (your code was missing them)
- There is no need to check length of `10` as regex will make sure that part as well
- As mentioned in comments earlier correct regex should be `^A[0-9]{3}-B[0-9]{4}$` or `^A[[:digit:]]{3}-B[[:digit:]]{4}$`

Answer (score 1):

Note that a regex like `^[A[0-9]{3}-B[0-9]{4}]$` matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[A[0-9]{3}` - three occurrences of `A`, `[` or a digit
- `-B` - a `-B` string
- `[0-9]{4}` - four digits
- `]` - a `]` char
- `$` - end of string.

So, it matches strings like `[A[-B1234]`, `[[[-B1939]`, etc.

Your regex checking line must look like

```bash
if [[ $tmp =~ ^A[0-9]{3}-B[0-9]{4}$ ]];then
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/33RPN5):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
tmp="A123-B1234";
if [[ $tmp =~ ^A[0-9]{3}-B[0-9]{4}$ ]];then
        msg="valid";
    else
        msg="invalid";
fi
echo $msg;
```

Output:

```
valid
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just `grep` might be easier:

```
$ echo A123-B1234 > valid.txt
$ echo 123 > invalid.txt
$ grep -Pq 'A\d{3}-B\d{4}' valid.txt && echo valid || echo invalid
valid
$ grep -Pq 'A\d{3}-B\d{4}' invalid.txt && echo valid || echo invalid
invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following code also.

```
#!/bin/bash
exp_len=10;
file=a.txt;
msg="checking string";
tmp="File not exist";

if [[ -f "$file" ]]
then
    echo "File named $file is existing.."
    awk '/^A[0-9]{3}-B[0-9]{4}$/{print "valid";next} {print "invalid"}' "$file"
else
    echo "Please do check File named $file is not existing, exiting from script now..."
    exit 1;
fi
```

***OR*** In case you want to check if line in your Input_file should be 10 characters long(by seeing OP's attempted code's `exp_len` shell variable) then try following code, where an additional condition is also added in `awk` code.

```
#!/bin/bash
exp_len=10;
file=a.txt;
msg="checking string";
tmp="File not exist";

if [[ -f "$file" ]]
then
    echo "File named $file is existing.."
    awk -v len="$exp_len" 'length($0) == len && /^A[0-9]{3}-B[0-9]{4}$/{print "valid";next} {print "invalid"}' "$file"
else
    echo "Please do check File named $file is not existing, exiting from script now..."
    exit 1;
fi
```

***NOTE:*** I am using here `-f` flag to test if file is existing or not, you can change it to `-s` eg: `-s "$file"` in case you want to check file is present and is of NOT NULL size.